# Apache beam WithTimestamps: Output timestamps must be no earlier than timestamp of current input

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, windowing

I am trying to window data from google cloud pubsub stream at a 10s frequency, however I get this error:

> > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot output with timestamp 2019-07-20T12:13:04.875Z. Output timestamps must be no earlier than the timestamp of the current input (2019-07-20T12:13:05.591Z) minus the allowed skew (0 milliseconds). See the DoFn#getAllowedTimestampSkew() Javadoc for details on changing the allowed skew.
> >             org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.checkTimestamp(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:587)
> >             org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.repackaged.org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.outputWithTimestamp(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:566)
> >             org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.outputWithTimestamp(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:80)
> >             org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.WithTimestamps$AddTimestampsDoFn.processElement(WithTimestamps.java:136)

Here is the code that causes the error:

```
eventStream
  .apply("Add Event Timestamps",
    WithTimestamps.of((Event event) -> new Instant(event.getTime())))
  .apply("Window Events",
    Window.<Event>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.parseDuration("10s"))));
```

What is the cause of this and what is a suitable solution?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> If the input {@link PCollection} elements have timestamps, the output
>   timestamp for each element must not be before the input element's
>   timestamp minus the value of {@link getAllowedTimestampSkew()}.  If an
>   output timestamp is before this time, the transform will throw an
>   {@link IllegalArgumentException} when executed. Use {@link
>   withAllowedTimestampSkew(Duration)} to update the allowed skew.
>
> CAUTION: Use of {@link #withAllowedTimestampSkew(Duration)} permits
>   elements to be emitted behind the watermark. These elements are
>   considered late, and if behind the {@link
>   Window#withAllowedLateness(Duration) allowed lateness} of a downstream
>   {@link PCollection} may be silently dropped.

So, to fix the issue you may play with `withAllowedTimestampSkew`.

I used a different API: `withTimestampAttribute`.
You can set an attribute in your JSON/AVRO that will contain the timestamp field.

This API is available when publish:

```java
  .apply(PubsubIO.writeAvros(Someclass.class)
         .withIdAttribute("id")
         .withTimestampAttribute("myTime").to(topic));
```

And when Subscribing:

```
.apply(PubsubIO.readAvros(Someclass.class) .fromSubscription(...)
       .withIdAttribute("id").withTimestampAttribute("myTime"))
```